Mailchimp integration in Flutter
I'm integrating the Mailchimp mobile SDK into my Flutter app. I'm using MethodChannel to call native Android/iOS code.
I successfully integrated but on Android it only works in debug mode. In release mode the contact doesn't get created. Does it need some extra permission to work in release?
This is the kotlin code that creates a contact:
val configuration = MailchimpSdkConfiguration.Builder(appContext, sdkKey)
    .isAutoTaggingEnabled(true)
    .build()
Mailchimp.initialize(configuration)

val newContact = Contact.Builder(email)
    .setContactStatus(ContactStatus.SUBSCRIBED)
    .build()
val sdk = Mailchimp.sharedInstance()
sdk.createOrUpdateContact(newContact)

Also in the documents the iOS code example shows how to check the result:
Mailchimp.createOrUpdate(contact: contact) { result in
    switch result {
    case .success:
        print("Successfully added or updated contact")
    case .failure(let error):
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

How to do the same on Android? I've tried using getStatusById but it only returns QUEUED and doesn't return if the contact has been created or not (doesn't wait for the response). It gives FAILED if i give an invalid email address:
val uuid = sdk.createOrUpdateContact(newContact)
val status = sdk.getStatusById(uuid) // status.name -> QUEUED/FAILED

How to wait for the result on Android?
What am I missing to work in release mode?

Do you have any logs to share of what happens in release mode?

I'm using sdk.getStatusById(uuid) to get the status, and it only returns FAILED, nothing more, no message, no explanation on why it fails, just a status.

I've found the issue, it's not related to Mailchimp. I post a answer if anyone has similar "works in debug but not in release" issues

In the app/build.gradle file when defining release build type, I had to set shrinkResources and minifyEnabled to false:
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        shrinkResources false
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}

